# Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/you/public_html/ccccc/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 228

Tags: error, fatal-error

Please I need your help anytime I try to login to my frontend as a re-seller I got an error message

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/you/public_html/ccccc/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 228
```

within my cpanel log error codes message:

Stack trace:

```
#0 /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/get.php(205): Varien_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http->send('/home2/xxxxxxxxx...')
#1 /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/get.php(165): sendFile('/home2/xxxxxxxxx...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Varien/File/Transfer/Adapter/Http.php on line 96
[06-May-2017 02:30:19 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'File '/home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/media/catalog/category/' does not exists.' in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Varien/File/Transfer/Adapter/Http.php:96
Stack trace:
#0 /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/get.php(205): Varien_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http->send('/home2/xxxxxxxxx...')
#1 /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/get.php(165): sendFile('/home2/xxxxxxxxx...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Varien/File/Transfer/Adapter/Http.php on line 96
[06-May-2017 03:30:33 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'File '/home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/media/catalog/category/' does not exists.' in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Varien/File/Transfer/Adapter/Http.php:96
Stack trace:
#0 /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/get.php(205): Varien_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http->send('/home2/xxxxxxxxx...')
#1 /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/get.php(165): sendFile('/home2/xxxxxxxxx...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Varien/File/Transfer/Adapter/Http.php on line 96
[06-May-2017 06:50:26 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'File '/home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/media/catalog/category/' does not exists.' in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Varien/File/Transfer/Adapter/Http.php:96
Stack trace:
#0 /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/get.php(205): Varien_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http->send('/home2/xxxxxxxxx...')
#1 /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/get.php(165): sendFile('/home2/xxxxxxxxx...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Varien/File/Transfer/Adapter/Http.php on line 96
[06-May-2017 07:00:42 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 1012
[06-May-2017 07:02:18 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Element.php on line 195
[06-May-2017 07:04:17 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php on line 336
[06-May-2017 07:05:28 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php on line 987
[06-May-2017 07:06:03 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 630
[06-May-2017 07:06:42 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php on line 508
[06-May-2017 07:07:23 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 931
[06-May-2017 07:08:00 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Zend/Locale/Format.php on line 1117
[06-May-2017 07:08:33 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Zend/Locale/Format.php on line 136
[06-May-2017 07:09:07 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Observer.php on line 113
[06-May-2017 07:09:40 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Varien/Object.php on line 401
[06-May-2017 07:10:13 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Varien/Db/Select.php on line 415
[06-May-2017 07:10:46 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Varien/Object.php on line 270
[06-May-2017 07:11:21 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php on line 0
[06-May-2017 07:11:53 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Element.php on line 242
[06-May-2017 07:12:29 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Select.php on line 975
[06-May-2017 07:13:03 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/app/Mage.php on line 0
[06-May-2017 07:13:36 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php on line 497
[06-May-2017 07:14:25 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/app/code/core/Zend/Date.php on line 574
[06-May-2017 07:14:58 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Zend/Locale/Data.php on line 1615
[06-May-2017 07:39:24 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Zend/Locale/Format.php on line 1113
[06-May-2017 07:41:34 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 519
[06-May-2017 07:44:14 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Varien/Object.php on line 246
[06-May-2017 07:44:50 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 1543
[06-May-2017 07:45:26 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Observer.php on line 254
[06-May-2017 07:46:03 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 433
[06-May-2017 07:46:39 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 1228
[06-May-2017 07:47:51 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Zend/Db/Profiler.php on line 117
[06-May-2017 07:48:27 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Abstract.php on line 0
[06-May-2017 07:49:01 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 291
[06-May-2017 08:23:04 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php on line 987
[06-May-2017 08:27:14 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 1043
[06-May-2017 08:31:35 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Zend/Locale/Data.php on line 1615
[06-May-2017 08:32:19 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php on line 1312
[06-May-2017 08:32:57 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Varien/Object.php on line 1149
[06-May-2017 08:33:31 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Select.php on line 740
[06-May-2017 08:34:07 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 974
[06-May-2017 08:34:47 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Varien/Object.php on line 636
[06-May-2017 08:35:24 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/app/code/core/Zend/Date.php on line 593
[06-May-2017 08:36:37 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Element.php on line 84
[06-May-2017 08:37:11 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Select.php on line 491
[06-May-2017 08:40:11 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 291
[06-May-2017 08:40:46 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php on line 275
[06-May-2017 08:41:26 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Select.php on line 979
[06-May-2017 08:42:00 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 680
[06-May-2017 08:42:58 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Varien/Object.php on line 270
[06-May-2017 08:59:41 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Zend/Locale/Format.php on line 1113
[06-May-2017 09:01:30 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Select.php on line 1018
[06-May-2017 09:02:08 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Varien/Object.php on line 401
[06-May-2017 09:02:19 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Resource/Rule.php on line 711
[06-May-2017 09:03:25 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Abstract.php on line 103
[06-May-2017 09:04:00 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 931
[06-May-2017 09:04:59 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 1044
[06-May-2017 09:06:57 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Varien/Db/Select.php on line 412
[06-May-2017 09:08:17 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Zend/Locale.php on line 297
[06-May-2017 09:09:12 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Varien/Object.php on line 635
[06-May-2017 09:10:51 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 148
[06-May-2017 09:15:43 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Varien/Object.php on line 108
[06-May-2017 09:16:17 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php on line 220
[06-May-2017 09:18:47 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php on line 292
[06-May-2017 09:19:22 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 0
[06-May-2017 09:19:56 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php on line 375
[06-May-2017 09:23:05 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'File '/home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/media/catalog/category/' does not exists.' in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Varien/File/Transfer/Adapter/Http.php:96
Stack trace:
#0 /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/get.php(205): Varien_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http->send('/home2/xxxxxxxxx...')
#1 /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/get.php(165): sendFile('/home2/xxxxxxxxx...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Varien/File/Transfer/Adapter/Http.php on line 96
[06-May-2017 09:30:54 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Varien/Object.php on line 401
[06-May-2017 09:31:29 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Element.php on line 153
[06-May-2017 09:32:01 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Varien/Db/Select.php on line 69
[06-May-2017 09:32:39 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote/Item/Collection.php on line 0
[06-May-2017 09:41:46 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 1615
[06-May-2017 10:38:01 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php on line 154
[06-May-2017 10:38:55 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php on line 851
[06-May-2017 11:00:53 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php on line 437
[06-May-2017 11:09:39 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 628
[06-May-2017 11:27:54 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'File '/home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/media/catalog/category/' does not exists.' in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Varien/File/Transfer/Adapter/Http.php:96
Stack trace:
#0 /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/get.php(205): Varien_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http->send('/home2/xxxxxxxxx...')
#1 /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/get.php(165): sendFile('/home2/xxxxxxxxx...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Varien/File/Transfer/Adapter/Http.php on line 96
[06-May-2017 11:28:53 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Zend/Locale/Format.php on line 827
[06-May-2017 11:29:28 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Resource/Rule.php on line 0
[06-May-2017 11:31:33 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php on line 587
[06-May-2017 11:33:55 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php on line 340
[06-May-2017 11:35:28 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 1333
[06-May-2017 11:36:14 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getItems() on null in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/app/code/local/Sm/Megamenu/Block/List.php on line 192
[06-May-2017 11:39:53 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 94 bytes) in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 291
[06-May-2017 11:40:45 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 670
[06-May-2017 11:41:46 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 81 bytes) in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 228
[06-May-2017 11:44:33 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /home2/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/cccccc/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 291
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its means that your request is very slowly, so you need to increase your *max_execution time*

```
max_execution_time = 300
```

or

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```

also you can changing the value for the param *max_execution_time* in *php.ini*, like this:

```
max_execution_time = 360      ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds (I CHANGED THIS VALUE)
max_input_time = 120          ; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
memory_limit = 128M           ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB by default)
```

or you change driver of request

also check if you have a infinite cycles
please increase your time-limit and use a profiler, like *blackfire.io* or similar and measure what exactly is eating all your time in your use-case.